# Is there a checklist on developing a web application from start to finish?

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications

1. Gather requirements
2. Figure out which programming language/DB to use
3. Ask mgr if it's okay
4. Design the database tables
5. Ask mgr if it looks okay
6. Mgr says to work with DBA
7. DBA says okay
8. I code a prototype
9. Senior developers, tell me how I should of coded it
10. I rework
11. Prototype almost finished
12. I present my progress to customer, they are happy so far, can I still meet the deadline? Yeah I say.
13. Mgr wants to see my progress
14. Mgr says I shouldn't use unique seq_key as unique identifier, use emp id, rename foreign keys, add columns, etc..
15. I rework db tables
16. I rework code and components to reflect db column changes
17. Now await mgr review, assuming more rework
18. Now I will not make my deadline with customer

Does this happen to the majority of developers?. What am I doing wrong, how can i streamline this process, how can I be more efficient?

Comment: You'll find better answers for this on programmers.stackexchange :)

Comment: Thanks, it's now posted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can make this more efficient by always be working on three different things.

1. What you'll show your manager to show you're 'making progress'
2. What you'll show your customers to show you're 'making progress'
3. What you're actually working on.

Neither your customer nor your manager have time to work out that the example you show them is bogus. Instead, they will be happy to see you making progress. Managers like to see diagrams. Customers like to see pretty interfaces. Make a few of those for your meetings, then spend spending time running everything you do by someone and more time actually working on the product.